# Make two arbitrary variables the same in Coq

Tags: coq

I have the following `coq` code:

```
Theorem filter_exercise : forall (X : Type) (l lf : list X) (test : X -> bool)
                             (x : X),
     filter test l = x :: lf ->
     test x = true.
Proof.
  intros X l lf test x eq.
  induction l as [|l' l].
  - inversion eq.
  - inversion eq as [H].
```

Which gives me:

```
  X : Type
  l' : X
  l, lf : list X
  test : X -> bool
  x : X
  eq : filter test (l' :: l) = x :: lf
  testEq : test x = false
  IHl : filter test l = x :: lf -> false = true
  ============================
  filter test l = (if test l' then l' :: filter test l else filter test l)
```

Here, if I could just say that because `test x = false` and both `x` and `l'` are universally quantified variables of type `X`, then I'd be done with the proof.

However, that's a semantic argument, and I'm not sure how to do that in Coq. Am I going down the wrong path?

**EDIT**

For posterity, this is the solution I ultimately obtained:

```
Theorem filter_exercise : forall (X : Type) (l lf : list X) (test : X -> bool)
                             (x : X),
     filter test l = x :: lf ->
     test x = true.
Proof.
  intros X l lf test x eq.
  induction l as [|l' l].
  - inversion eq.
  - simpl in eq. destruct (test l') eqn:testl'.
    + inversion eq. rewrite <- H0. apply testl'.
    + apply IHl. apply eq.
Qed.
```

Comment: Is your argument that `test l' = false` too? That's not true.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia yes, that's my argument; semantically, if `test x = false` is true, shouldn't `test l' = false` be true too, since both `x` and `l'` are universally quantified variables?

Comment: No. Think about it this way: because the theorem considers all functions `test` and all lists `l`, there are cases where `test` will evaluate to `true`, but the only case where you consider the value of `test` on the next element of `l`, you are arguing that it has to be `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "semantic argument", but this proof strategy is not correct, neither on paper nor in Coq.  Consider, for instance, the following statement:

```
Lemma faulty : forall n m : nat, even n -> even m.
Proof. Admitted.
```

By your logic, if `n` is even, then `m` should also be even, since both are universally quantified variables of type `nat`. However, precisely *because* they are universally quantified, they can instantiated to different values of `nat`, thus yielding obviously contradictory statements.  For instance, if we instantiate  `faulty` with 2 and 1, we should be able to conclude that 1 is even, which is not true.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument that `test x = false -> test l' = false` is not true, as both variables `x` and `l` are universally quantified, and thus can have any value. You could just have a specific relationship between both variables in your hypothesis, but here it is not the case, except the relationship `filter test (l' :: l) = x :: lf`, that tells you that x could be an element of l which has not been filtered by test (but it also might be l').

You should not use `inversion` here, as your problem is really simple. You idea to perform an induction is fine however :

- Try first to simplify several hypothesis.
- Then see if there are different cases to deal with, and use `destruct` when needed (on the value of `test l'` in this problem)
- You should be able to solve the problem then (the most complicated tactic you might have to use is `injection`)